# In the figure, the polygons shown are regular. Find $"x"$.

Tags: geometry

For reference:
[image]

my progress:

I marked the angles I could find but couldn't finish

$a_{i9} = \frac{180(n-2)}{n}=\frac{180(9-2}{9}=\angle140^\circ\\a_{i6}= \frac{180(6-2)}{6}=\angle120^\circ\\\angle ADB = \frac{360^\circ-2(140^\circ)}{2} = \angle 40^\circ\\\angle BJI = \frac{\angle 180^\circ-\angle 120^\circ}{2}=30^\circ\\a_{i5}= \frac{180(5-2)}{5}=\angle108^\circ\\\\
S_{ai5} = 180(n-2) = 180(5-2) =\angle 540^\circ \\
\angle HDE = \frac{540 - 3(140)}{2}=\angle 60^\circ$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lengthen $BA$ to the left and find the angles those it makes with $AM$ and $AL$. Then using them find $\angle MAL$ and $\angle LAN$. Then you can find $\angle ANL$ and eventually $x$.

Comment: I have achieved $\angle MAN$ as $100˚$ and $\angle MNA$ as $40˚$ from the angles on parallel lines theorem. How to continue from here??

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking of the 4-sided shape BANO instead $\triangle BAN$.

Comment: @ACB  I find $\angle MAL = 20^\circ ~and \angle LAN=80^\circ$ but ididn't $\angle ALN$.. can you demonstrate?

Comment: @petaarantes ,Use Troposphere's hint then. It's a isosceles triangle. I didn't mention it in my answer because he has mentioned. $AN=AL$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\triangle BAN$ is isosceles (because $ABCN$ is a rhombus), and therefore so is $\triangle NAL$.